# Firefox and Chrome append punctuation to downloaded filename

Tags: cross-browser

I am trying to download a file from a local web server. While IE works fine, Firefox appends an underscore at the end of the filename and Chrome appends hyphensemi-colon at the end.

Any pointers to look at?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you write the server code to transmit the file?

Comment: No. I am trying to fix a bug.

Comment: A bug with what?  How do you propose to fix this if you have no control over the server?

Comment: I mean I have access to the code. This is the bug I am trying to fix but not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I believe the issue is because of this:  res.setContentType("application/octet-stream; name=\""+ utf8Filename +"\"") ;
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "anything; filename="+ utf8Filename + "\";") ; But not sure what change would resolve the issue with FF and Chrome

Comment: Resolved this issue. Had to remove the semicolon inside the setHeader method and add a matching (escaping) quote after anything:filename